# How to delete header and footer except shaperange

Tags: vba, header, ms-word, shapes

The header and footer can be removed by using delete command. But I want to delete everything from header/footer except Shapes. There are two ranges: TextRange and ShapesRange. The ShapeRange can be accessed as below.

```
    For Each sec In worddoc.Sections
        For Each hdr In sec.Headers
            For Each sh In hdr.Shapes
                If sh.Left > 200 Then
                    'Do something
                End If
            Next sh
        Next hdr
    Next sec
```

How to delete TextRange?

By setting .TextRange="" will remove tables,textboxes?

Comment: I want to delete all text, fields(textbox), tables from header except shapes.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ctl As ContentControl
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

        On Error Resume Next
        '~~> Delete all controls like textbox label etc
        For Each ctl In .ContentControls
            ctl.Delete
        Next

        '~~> Delete all tables
        For Each tbl In .Tables
            tbl.Delete
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0

        '~~> Delete all printable/non printable characters
        For i = 0 To 255
            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Text = Chr(i)
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next i
    End With

    MsgBox "Done" 

End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]